# Java swing/awt jar for android?

Tags: android, java, user-interface

I want to port my existing Java with minimal recoding of the ui. I need a jar library that uses Android api's to create an application ui with only code. It is preferable if the API is similar to swing/awt, but that is not required. I am looking for basically an android ui code library.